# Python nltk is giving me multiple instances of the sentence in result

Tags: python, nltk

This is my code

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
>>> corpus_root = 'C:/Python27/'
>>> wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,'amazonshoes.txt')
>>> sentences = wordlists.sents('amazonshoes.txt')
>>> words_to_find = 'amazon service'.split()
>>> for sentence in sentences:
...     if all(word in sentence for word in words_to_find):
...         print sentence
```

and the result is

```
['review', '/', 'text', ':', 'It', "'", 's', 'the', 'first', 'time', 'that', 'I', 'buy', 'something', 'over', 'amazon', 'and', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'say', 'I', 'am', 'very', 'impressed', 'with', 'the', 'service', 'and', 'the', 'quality', 'of', 'the', 'product', '.']
['review', '/', 'text', ':', 'It', "'", 's', 'the', 'first', 'time', 'that', 'I', 'buy', 'something', 'over', 'amazon', 'and', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'say', 'I', 'am', 'very', 'impressed', 'with', 'the', 'service', 'and', 'the', 'quality', 'of', 'the', 'product', '.']
['review', '/', 'text', ':', 'It', "'", 's', 'the', 'first', 'time', 'that', 'I', 'buy', 'something', 'over', 'amazon', 'and', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'say', 'I', 'am', 'very', 'impressed', 'with', 'the', 'service', 'and', 'the', 'quality', 'of', 'the', 'product', '.']
['review', '/', 'text', ':', 'It', "'", 's', 'the', 'first', 'time', 'that', 'I', 'buy', 'something', 'over', 'amazon', 'and', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'say', 'I', 'am', 'very', 'impressed', 'with', 'the', 'service', 'and', 'the', 'quality', 'of', 'the', 'product', '.']
['review', '/', 'text', ':', 'It', "'", 's', 'the', 'first', 'time', 'that', 'I', 'buy', 'something', 'over', 'amazon', 'and', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'say', 'I', 'am', 'very', 'impressed', 'with', 'the', 'service', 'and', 'the', 'quality', 'of', 'the', 'product', '.']
```

what should I change in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your `sentences` list already contains duplicates. Or change your code like that:

```
>>> for sentence in set([tuple(s) for s in sentences]):
...     if all(word in sentence for word in words_to_find):
...         print sentence
```

The change makes sure that you have the set of unique sentences (the change converts your lists to tuples, because list is not hashable).

Comment: its a pretty big corpora, but I did check it though not entirely. It doesnot repeat any reviews.